# How to add value to the team

Tags: performance

Can you please advise how to get better at adding value to the work I do /team(at the same time keeping my skills updated )?

I feel a lot happy when I have made an impact.

So we are going to have a baby , so I want to optimize my work the best way possible to be done in short time possible so I dont impact the WLB.

Year of industry experience:14 .

Year of experience in this new role : <1 year

Tech Worker

Role/Responsibilities:

```
Project Management
Product Management
Developer in Python,Java,bash scripting, sql
Cloud skills - Kubernetes,Docker
```

Comment: With all due respect, if you haven't worked out after 14 years how to add value to a team I'm not sure there's much we can do to help.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I feel imposter syndrome lot of times and would like to improve. So your comments didnt really help

Comment: This is not a very well posed question.  Please add some specific details about what responsibilities the team has in front of it that you feel unable to address.

Comment: @jwh20 Added. There are lot of different domains skills which are needed for this role and pulling me in all directions. I edited question with few of them

Comment: Apart from Project and Product Management, the developer and cloud skills seem to me to be pretty fundamental.  If you can't work with at least most of these you are in real danger of becoming obsolete.  With 14 years of experience you should be a leader on your team not looking to fall off the trailing edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about Impostor Syndrome. In IT field we all feel from time to time, because we are never fully seniors. Tech changes so fast and we constantly have to learn new things. Those who claim otherwise are usually the ones that majority of the team finds it difficult to interact and work with because they are so sure on their skills and they put themselves on a pedestal. In general, be critical of yourself and most importantly keep asking for feedback from peers. People don't usually tend to come and tell you what you can improve cause they are afraid of hurting you somehow, but when you come then and show genuine interest in hearing feedback they open up and feel at ease to tell you.

So the best people to ask are really your currently co-workers. Don't ask this kind of help here in StackExchange. You will get people who are always on the watch for a question they will judge "not fit" and instead of helping or just ignoring it, they will make sure to say something that will just bring you down. It makes them feel better about themselves. Just ignore it. You are never too senior to be learning and re-learning, you did good in asking for the advice. Just not at the right place